# \mathcal isn't the one by default but out a package I dont know

Tags: fonts

When I use the command \mathcal, it returns the same font at the command \mathfrak.

I thought it's maybe because of a package that changes the default outcome of the command \mathcal. Do you know which one ? Or do you have another explanation ?

Here's the list of all the packages I imported:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[upright]{fourier}
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb}
\usepackage[thmmarks, amsmath]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{color,soul}
\usepackage{soulutf8}
\usepackage{xpatch}
```

Thank you !

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! You load  `fourier`, which defines its own calligraphic font, matching the main font (it looks like `mathrsfs`).

Comment: Just as a side note, it wouldn't take you long to figure out which package is the cause. Make a new document, add `\documentclass{article}`, then all your packages, then `\begin{document} $\mathcal{F}$ \end{document}`. Comment out one package at a time, compiling the document between each time, and you'll quickly see which package is the culprit.

Comment: `amsmath \leq mathtools` as package.